# Need help with roslaunch openhrp3 falling-box.launch?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I execute: roslaunch openhrp3 falling-box.launch   ----Eclipse is invoked and I see the IDE but the start button(s) is disabled. When I use menu GrxUI->Start Simulation, the Graph tab shows 3 windows that seem to be working. The 3D view tab does not have any falling boxes in it. The 3D view tab is blank. What should I do?             Also, when I click on the falling-boxes.launch link on the   http://code.google.com/p/rtm-ros-robotics/wiki/ROS_English   page, I get:

Google

404. That’s an error.

The requested URL /p/rtm-ros-robotics/source/browse/tags/latest/rtmros_common/openhrp3/launch/faling-boxes.launch was not found on this server. That’s all we know.

Also, here is the transcript of the terminal messages:
sam@Mecha:~$ roslaunch openhrp3 falling-box.launch
... logging to /home/sam/.ros/log/2faa415a-a6ec-11e1-a8e5-406186e58fd3/roslaunch-Mecha-22078.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://Mecha:53041/

## SUMMARY

PARAMETERS

- /rosversion
- /rosdistro

NODES
/
rtm_naming (openrtm/rtm-naming-restart)
hrpsys_kill_all (openhrp3/openhrp-shutdown-servers)
grxui (openhrp3/grxui.sh)

WARNING: unrecognized tag sphinxdoc
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[rtm_naming-1]: started with pid [22096]
process[hrpsys_kill_all-2]: started with pid [22098]
/home/sam/prog/rtm-ros-robotics/rtm-ros-robotics/rtmros_common/openrtm/scripts/rtm-naming-restart: line 53: 21875 Killed                  $cosnames -start $port -logdir $currdir
openhrp-aist-dynamics-simulator: no process found
openhrp-collision-detector: no process found
openhrp-model-loader: no process found
openhrp-controller-bridge: no process found
openhrp-path-planner: no process found
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
[hrpsys_kill_all-2] process has finished cleanly.
log file: /home/sam/.ros/log/2faa415a-a6ec-11e1-a8e5-406186e58fd3/hrpsys_kill_all-2*.log

Fri May 25 22:37:53 2012:

Starting omniNames for the first time.
Wrote initial log file.
Read log file successfully.
Root context is IOR:010000002b00000049444c3a6f6d672e6f72672f436f734e616d696e672f4e616d696e67436f6e746578744578743a312e300000010000000000000070000000010102000d0000003139322e3136382e302e31320000f90a0b0000004e616d6553657276696365000300000000000000080000000100000000545441010000001c000000010000000100010001000000010001050901010001000000090101000354544108000000215ec04f01005665
Checkpointing Phase 1: Prepare.
Checkpointing Phase 2: Commit.
Checkpointing completed.
process[grxui-3]: started with pid [22119]

Fri May 25 22:52:53 2012:

Checkpointing Phase 1: Prepare.
Checkpointing Phase 2: Commit.
Checkpointing completed.
ALSO, there are 2 archives at /build/ that I am not installing since the instructions don't say to install them. The 2 archives are: rtmtools100release_en.zip and j3d-1_5_2-linux-amd64.zip  ( I have a 64 bit linux )  Should I install those two archives?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34891/need-help-with-roslaunch-openhrp3-falling-box.launch-!!/) by [TurtleBot_Fan](https://answers.ros.org/users/702/turtlebot_fan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2012-05-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solution for: simulation of Falling Boxes not rendering

The debugging process:

1- Ensured that manual installation of eclipse software was done

1.1 see http://code.google.com/p/rtm-ros-robotics/wiki/ROS_English#Setup_Eclipse

1.2 Also check trouble shooting list. See http://code.google.com/p/rtm-ros-robotics
/wiki/ROS_English#Troubleshooting

1.3 When installing GEF SDK 3.6.2 these errors ok
sam@Mecha:~/prog/rtm-ros-robotics/rtm-ros-robotics/rtmros_common/openhrp3$
rosrun openhrp3 eclipse.sh I: Injected update sites

```
   * (Eclipse:3261): CRITICAL *: murrine_style_draw_box: assertion `height >= -1' 
   failed
   * (Eclipse:3261): CRITICAL *: murrine_style_draw_box: assertion `height >= -1'
   failed
   * (Eclipse:3261): CRITICAL *: murrine_style_draw_box: assertion `height >= -1'
   failed
   * (Eclipse:3261): CRITICAL *: murrine_style_draw_box: assertion `height >= -1'
   failed
   * (Eclipse:3261): CRITICAL *: murrine_style_draw_box: assertion `height >= -1' 
   failed
   * (Eclipse:3261): CRITICAL *: murrine_style_draw_box: assertion `height >= -1'
   failed
```

1.4 Did the following command
sam@Mecha:~$ roscd rtmros_common; svn up

```
  U hrpsys/launch/hrp4c.launch U hrpsys/Makefile.hrpsys-base Conflict discovered 
  in 'hrpsys/index.rst'. Select: (p) postpone, (df) diff-full, (e) edit, (mc)  
  mine-conflict, (tc) theirs-conflict, (s) show all options: 
  (Select the tc option.)
```

2- Ran sam@Mecha:~$ glxgears

Error: couldn't get an RGB, Double-buffered visual If you meant to select a
glxgears project .xml file, I didn't see one available
(now we know something is wrong with the display driver)

3- Used System->Preferences->Screensaver->GLMatrix to verify that GLMatrix would not
render

4- Ran:
sudo apt-get install --reinstall l freeglut3-dev build-essential libx11-dev
libxmu-dev libxi-dev libgl1-mesa-glx libglu1-mesa libglu1-mesa-dev (to ensure the
mesa software was installed properly)

Ran: sam@Mecha:~$ glxgears

Error: couldn't get an RGB, Double-buffered visual

Also ran: sam@Mecha:~$ glxinfo | grep '^direct rendering:'

Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig

(problem is not mesa software)

5- Ran:
export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1

then glxgears WORKS! but the simulation still does not work and GLMatrix
screensaver still doesn't work. Newer versions of the GLX library favor direct
software rendering over accelerated indirect rendering

6- To see who the libGL files I ran:

sam@Mecha:~$ ls -al /usr/lib/libGL*

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  487480 2010-01-17 00:07 /usr/lib/libGLEW.a

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 2012-05-23 17:03 /usr/lib/libGLEW.so ->libGLEW.so.1.5.2

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 2012-05-23 17:03 /usr/lib/libGLEW.so.1.5 ->libGLEW.so.1.5.2

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  358456 2010-01-17 00:07 /usr/lib/libGLEW.so.1.5.2

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     654 2011-07-29 03:02 /usr/lib/libGL.la

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      13 2012-05-26 10:23 /usr/lib/libGL.so -> mesa/libGL.so

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      15 2011-07-29 03:02 /usr/lib/libGL.so.1 ->libGL.so.275.21

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1023120 2011-07-29 03:02 /usr/lib/libGL.so.275.21

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  929838 2010-04-28 23:54 /usr/lib/libGLU.a

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      11 2012-05-26 10:23 /usr/lib/libGLU.so -> libGLU.so.1

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      20 2012-05-26 01:55 /usr/lib/libGLU.so.1 ->libGLU.so.1.3.070701

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  461488 2010-04-28 23:54 /usr/lib/libGLU.so.1.3.070701

When the files were displayed only two were displayed in light green font:

/usr/lib/libGL.so.1 -> libGL.so.275.21  (this one is a symbolic link)

/usr/lib/libGL.so.275.21

These files have the version number of a proprietary installation of an NVidia
display driver

7- I ran :

sam@Mecha:~$ dpkg -S libGL.so.275.21  (finds owner of package)

The result stated that the package did not exist. So now we know the Nvidia
installation is invalid, so we can ignore it and proceed to install the NVidia
binary X.Org driver (version 185) display driver available in the Ubuntu Software
Center.

8- Ran:
glxgears...and it worked.

GLMatrix screensaver... and it worked

OpenHRP Falling Boxes simulation....and it worked

They all worked, but were running slowly.

9- To see if OpenGL is using direct rendering or indirect rendering I ran:

sam@Mecha:~$ glxinfo | grep -i render

direct rendering: No (If you want to find out why, try setting LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose)
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce GTS 450/PCI/SSE2

So, now we know we are using indirect rendering instead of direct rendering.
If the OpenGL renderer string says "software" in it, then their drivers are not installed properly, even if direct rendering shows "Yes". Direct rendering is better because the rendering is faster.

10- Rebooted the computer.....and then ran:

sam@Mecha:~$ glxinfo | grep -i render

direct rendering: Yes
OpenGL renderer string: unknown board/PCI/SSE2
GL_KTX_buffer_region, GL_NV_blend_square, GL_NV_conditional_render,
GL_NVX_conditional_render, GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info,

11- Everything then worked properly and all was solved.

---

Originally posted by [TurtleBot_Fan](https://answers.ros.org/users/702/turtlebot_fan/) with karma: 287 on 2012-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have to manually install software to the eclipse, see http://code.google.com/p/rtm-ros-robotics/wiki/ROS_English#Setup_Eclipse
Also check trouble shooting list. See http://code.google.com/p/rtm-ros-robotics/wiki/ROS_English#Troubleshooting

---

Originally posted by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) with karma: 1186 on 2012-05-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TurtleBot_Fan](https://answers.ros.org/users/702/turtlebot_fan/) on 2012-05-25**:
I already did manual install of software to Eclipse, but I followed the troubleshooting and did it again.  When I did the first install of GEF SDK 3.6.2 i got these errors. iare these errors ok? sam@Mecha:~/prog/rtm-ros-robotics/rtm-ros-robotics/rtmros_common/openhrp3$ rosrun openhrp3 eclipse.sh
I: Injected update sites

** (Eclipse:3261): CRITICAL **: murrine_style_draw_box: assertion `height >= -1' failed

** (Eclipse:3261): CRITICAL **: murrine_style_draw_box: assertion `height >= -1' failed

** (Eclipse:3261): CRITICAL **: murrine_style_draw_box: assertion `height >= -1' failed

** (Eclipse:3261): CRITICAL **: murrine_style_draw_box: assertion `height >= -1' failed

** (Eclipse:3261): CRITICAL **: murrine_style_draw_box: assertion `height >= -1' failed

** (Eclipse:3261): CRITICAL **: murrine_style_draw_box: assertion `height >= -1' failed

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2012-05-25**:
For a falling box example, java3declipse-20090302.zip and grxui_eclipse.zip are important. since you have trouble on opengl library, i suppose you'd better to reinstall the these eclipse plugins.

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2012-05-25**:
be sure that you have opengl properly installed by running glxgears and check if you can see "gears".

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2012-05-25**:
To reinstall the eclipse plugins, roscd openhrp3; make wipe; then run eclipse and remove insalled plugin (you can remove installed plugin from Help > Install New Software > already installed), roscd openhrp3; make; then install plugins again.

**Comment by [TurtleBot_Fan](https://answers.ros.org/users/702/turtlebot_fan/) on 2012-05-25**:
I redid all manual install with same bad result. I then did the following, but do not know how to continue with presented choices ?!: sam@Mecha:~$ roscd rtmros_common; svn up
U    hrpsys/launch/hrp4c.launch
U    hrpsys/Makefile.hrpsys-base
Conflict discovered in 'hrpsys/index.rst'.
Select: (p) postpone, (df) diff-full, (e) edit,
        (mc) mine-conflict, (tc) theirs-conflict,
        (s) show all options: 
What should I do?            I did: sam@Mecha:~$ glxgears
Error: couldn't get an RGB, Double-buffered visual
If you meant to select a glxgears project .xml file, I didn't see one available.

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2012-05-25**:
select tc, sorry for inconvenience. we know this is the problem, but not fixed yet.

**Comment by [TurtleBot_Fan](https://answers.ros.org/users/702/turtlebot_fan/) on 2012-05-25**:
It's ok about inconvenience. I selected tc and then did: rosmake hrpsys hrpsys_ros_bridge and it completed without errors. I did all the troubleshooting, and seemed ok except I could never get any simulation graphics in 3d tab. I do not know what else to do. Everything seems to be working except for the 3D part of the simulation of falling boxes.   One interesting side-effect from installing rtm-ros-robotics is my Matrix screensaver stopped rendering(!)

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2012-05-25**:
be sure that you have opengl properly installed by running glxgears and check if you can see "gears". If not you still have opengl problems. apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-dev libgl1-mesa-glx libglu1-mesa-dev

**Comment by [TurtleBot_Fan](https://answers.ros.org/users/702/turtlebot_fan/) on 2012-05-26**:
I did: sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-dev libgl1-mesa-glx libglu1-mesa-dev
sam@Mecha:~$ glxgears
Error: couldn't get an RGB, Double-buffered visual           Also did: sam@Mecha:~$ glxinfo | grep '^direct rendering:'
Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig
Here are some interesting facts: 1- When first installing Ubuntu 10.04, OpenGL is automatically installed.  2- GLMatrix screensaver rendered fine before installing rtm-ros-robotics, now GLMatix screensaver does not render   3- After compiling 116 packages with zero failure and doing all troublingshooting steps, OpenGL is broken now, when it wasn't broken earlier. 4- Reinstalling OpenGL doesn't help for some reason  5- glxgears produces Error: couldn't get an RGB, Double-buffered visual 6- glxinfo | grep '^direct rendering:' produces Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig   7- It will take me a long time to solve the OpenGL problem on my own since I am not a linux expert and will need to mine the internet for a solution

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2012-05-26**:
$ ls -al /usr/lib/libGL*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     13 2012-01-26 23:43 /usr/lib/libGL.so -> mesa/libGL.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 929838 2010-04-29 14:54 /usr/lib/libGLU.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     11 2012-01-26 23:43 /usr/lib/libGLU.so -> libGLU.so.1

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2012-05-26**:
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     20 2012-01-24 11:59 /usr/lib/libGLU.so.1 -> libGLU.so.1.3.070701
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 461488 2010-04-29 14:54 /usr/lib/libGLU.so.1.3.070701
lokada@lucid-amd64:~$ ls -al /usr/lib/mesa/libGL*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   10 2012-01-26 23:43 /usr/lib/mesa/libGL.so -> libGL.so.1

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2012-05-26**:
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     12 2012-01-24 11:59 /usr/lib/mesa/libGL.so.1 -> libGL.so.1.2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 527200 2010-04-29 14:54 /usr/lib/mesa/libGL.so.1.2

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2012-05-26**:
From previous post, it seems that you installed nvidia driver ant it conflicts with opengl from ubuntu. Can you uninstall nvidia driver ? how do you installed? check that /usr/lib/libGL.so and /usr/lib/libGLU.so symbolic links are correctly pointed ubuntu driver (mesa, not nvidia) as above comments

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2012-05-26**:
checking ldd$ ldd /usr/bin/glxgears
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffe3b0f000)
libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/mesa/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f5f937c3000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007f5f93540000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f5f93209000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f5f

**Comment by [TurtleBot_Fan](https://answers.ros.org/users/702/turtlebot_fan/) on 2012-05-26**:
This is what I did:  These show the symbolic links right?  If so, do they look good to you? sam@Mecha:~$ ls -al /usr/lib/libGL*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  487480 2010-01-17 00:07 /usr/lib/libGLEW.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 2012-05-23 17:03 /usr/lib/libGLEW.so -> libGLEW.so.1.5.2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 2012-05-23 17:03 /usr/lib/libGLEW.so.1.5 -> libGLEW.so.1.5.2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  358456 2010-01-17 00:07 /usr/lib/libGLEW.so.1.5.2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     654 2011-07-29 03:02 /usr/lib/libGL.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      13 2012-05-26 10:23 /usr/lib/libGL.so -> mesa/libGL.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      15 2011-07-29 03:02 /usr/lib/libGL.so.1 -> libGL.so.275.21
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1023120 2011-07-29 03:02 /usr/lib/libGL.so.275.21
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  929838 2010-04-28 23:54 /usr/lib/libGLU.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      11 2012-05-26 10:23 /usr/lib/libGLU.so -> libGLU.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      20 2012-05-26 01:55 /usr/lib/libGLU.so.1 -> libGLU.so.1.3.070701
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  461488 2010-04-28 23:54 /usr/lib/libGLU.so.1.3.070701

**Comment by [TurtleBot_Fan](https://answers.ros.org/users/702/turtlebot_fan/) on 2012-05-26**:
Also I found out that if I do: export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1      then glxgears WORKS!!  but the simulation still does not work and GLMatrix screensaver still not work. Newer versions of the GLX library favor direct software rendering over accelerated indirect rendering.  I do not know how to make it work with direct rendering at this time.

**Comment by [TurtleBot_Fan](https://answers.ros.org/users/702/turtlebot_fan/) on 2012-05-26**:
I don't remember how I installed NVIDIA drivers or if I even did that.....too many years ago.

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2012-05-26**:
you have /usr/lib/libGL.so.275.21, that will comes from nvidia , dpkg -S libGL.so.275.21 to see who installed that

**Comment by [TurtleBot_Fan](https://answers.ros.org/users/702/turtlebot_fan/) on 2012-05-26**:
I did: sam@Mecha:/lib$ sudo dpkg -S libGL.so.275.21
dpkg: *libGL.so.275.21* not found.

**Comment by [TurtleBot_Fan](https://answers.ros.org/users/702/turtlebot_fan/) on 2012-05-26**:
/usr/lib/libGL.so.275.21  is a SYMBOLIC link that must be changed to point at mesa right?  If so, what is the command(s) to accomplish this symbolic link redirection?  (I feel we are getting closer to solving this, thank you for your patience)  Also did:  sam@Mecha:~$ dpkg -s libGL.so.275.21
Package `libgl.so.275.21' is not installed and no info is available.
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2012-05-26**:
if dpkg -S XXX does not returns the answer (see dpkg -S libGL.so instead), this means that files (in this case libGL.so.275.21) should not  exist.

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2012-05-26**:
/usr/lib/libGL.so -> mesa/libGL.so, /usr/lib/mesa/libGL.so -> libGL.so.1, /usr/lib/mesa/libGL.so.1 -> libGL.so.1.2, /usr/lib/mesa/libGL.so.1.2 (527200 byte). BTW how do you paste such a long message?

**Comment by [TurtleBot_Fan](https://answers.ros.org/users/702/turtlebot_fan/) on 2012-05-27**:
I'm confused about the /usr/lib/libGL.so.275.21 file not existing because it shows up in light green when I do sam@Mecha:~$ ls -al /usr/lib/libGL*.   -----------To paste a long message I just copy the output in a terminal and paste it here. Then when I have more to paste later I do and 'edit'. What bothers me is that on my side all the words are strung together in a big sentence without any way to format them so it would be easier for you to read. If I try hitting the enter key to go to next line, the message gets submitted. What do we try now??

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2012-05-27**:
I'd like to make sure that you have /usr/lib/libGL.so.1. is it light? which I don't have. Please check if it will installed outside of ubuntu package system. if dpkg -S /usr/lib/libGL.so.1 returns error, you can remove /usr/lib/libGL.so.1 file

**Comment by [TurtleBot_Fan](https://answers.ros.org/users/702/turtlebot_fan/) on 2012-05-27**:
/usr/lib/libGL.so.1 is shown in light green. I did the following command to find all occurrences of /usr/lib/libGL.so.1 on my system.......and it seems /usr/lib//libGL.so.1 does not exist........this is the result:  -------------------------------------sam@Mecha:~$ apt-file search libGL.so.1
fglrx: /usr/lib/fglrx/libGL.so.1
fglrx: /usr/lib/fglrx/libGL.so.1.2
fglrx: /usr/lib32/fglrx/libGL.so.1.2
ia32-libs: /usr/lib32/mesa/libGL.so.1
ia32-libs: /usr/lib32/mesa/libGL.so.1.2
libgl1-mesa-glx: /usr/lib/mesa/libGL.so.1
libgl1-mesa-glx: /usr/lib/mesa/libGL.so.1.2
libgl1-mesa-glx-dbg: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/mesa/libGL.so.1.2
libgl1-mesa-swx11: /usr/lib/mesa/libGL.so.1
libgl1-mesa-swx11: /usr/lib/mesa/libGL.so.1.5.070701
libgl1-mesa-swx11-dbg: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/mesa/libGL.so.1.5.070701
nvidia-173: /usr/lib/nvidia-173/libGL.so.1
nvidia-173: /usr/lib/nvidia-173/libGL.so.173.14.22
nvidia-173: /usr/lib32/nvidia-173/libGL.so.1
nvidia-173: /usr/lib32/nvidia-173/libGL.so.173.14.22
nvidia-96: /usr/lib/nvidia-96/libGL.so.1
nvidia-96: /usr/lib32/nvidia-96/libGL.so.1
nvidia-current: /usr/lib/nvidia-current/libGL.so.1
nvidia-current: /usr/lib/nvidia-current/libGL.so.195.36.15
nvidia-current: /usr/lib/nvidia-current/libGL.so.195.36.24
nvidia-current: /usr/lib32/nvidia-current/libGL.so.1
nvidia-current: /usr/lib32/nvidia-current/libGL.so.195.36.15
nvidia-current: /usr/lib32/nvidia-current/libGL.so.195.36.24     ------------------------------------------- I don't see how to check if it will install outside of ubuntu package system; how do I do this?

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2012-05-27**:
You did install both nvidia and giregl package, how about; sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx nvidia-current; sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-dev libgl1-mesa-glx libglu1-mesa-dev

**Comment by [TurtleBot_Fan](https://answers.ros.org/users/702/turtlebot_fan/) on 2012-05-28**:
I got the following: sam@Mecha:~$ sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx nvidia-current
[sudo] password for sam: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package fglrx is not installed, so not removed
Package nvidia-current is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 158 not upgraded.    ----------------------------------------------------------------I then didL -------------------sam@Mecha:~$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-dev libgl1-mesa-glx libglu1-mesa-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 3 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 158 not upgraded.
Need to get 0B/398kB of archives.
After this operation, 0B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
(Reading database ... 240072 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace libgl1-mesa-glx 7.7.1-1ubuntu3 (using .../libgl1-mesa-glx_7.7.1-1ubuntu3_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libgl1-mesa-glx ...
Preparing to replace libglu1-mesa-dev 7.7.1-1ubuntu3 (using .../libglu1-mesa-dev_7.7.1-1ubuntu3_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libglu1-mesa-dev ...
Preparing to replace libgl1-mesa-dev 7.7.1-1ubuntu3 (using .../libgl1-mesa-dev_7.7.1-1ubuntu3_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libgl1-mesa-dev ...
Setting up libgl1-mesa-glx (7.7.1-1ubuntu3) ...

Setting up libgl1-mesa-dev (7.7.1-1ubuntu3) ...
Setting up libglu1-mesa-dev (7.7.1-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
sam@Mecha:~$ glxgears
Error: couldn't get an RGB, Double-buffered visual

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2012-05-28**:
Oh, you used apt-file in the previous comment, that is not for finding a package in you system, but to find a package in the ubuntu repository. So, /usr/lib/libGL.so.1 -> libGL.so.275.21 is the starnge. dpkg -S /usr/lib/libGL.so.275.21  (not -s , but -S ) returns not found, you can remove the file,

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2012-05-28**:
You also better to remove /usr/lib/libGL.so.1, after checking dpkg -S /usr/lib/libGL.so.1. That file also did not installed from ubuntu system, I suppose.

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2012-05-28**:
after that, you can check by ldd `which glxgears` and that should show  libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/mesa/libGL.so.1 (0x00007ffd9aef3000)

**Comment by [TurtleBot_Fan](https://answers.ros.org/users/702/turtlebot_fan/) on 2012-05-28**:
Hey!!!  I found the solution! It turned out, after a lot of digging, that I did manually install a proprietary version of an Nvidia display driver long ago when the Ubuntu 10.04 LTS was first released.  Here is the solution for your future reference. ----1- When Ubuntu10.04 is initially installed, an open source display driver called Nouveau is automatically installed. 2- When installing a proprietary driver to use instead of Nouveau (in this case an Nvidia driver)  it is best to do it as described at this URL: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sh4ZmBdFCuU  ----It is best to use the Ubuntu Software Center to install proprietary display drivers. If one chooses to bypass the Ubuntu Software Center  by manually installing a proprietary display driver form the proprietary website, updates to the driver will not occur because the Ubuntu Software Center  will not recognize the installation done outside the Ubuntu Software Center purview. Problems with conflicts (like the kind we had) will almost certainly occur later as a side-effect of not using the Ubuntu Software Center . 3- Used the Ubuntu Software Center  to install NVidia binary X.Org driver (version 185) (not the latest version though) and all my OpenGL applications worked, but in indirect rendering only (which was bad because it's too slow). 4- I booted ny machine and then the direct rendering was enabled! ----------Thank you so much for your infinite patience and help. -------- Two side questiona:--Is there any documentation available for each of the simulations? Is there a way to have the simulation run faster?

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2012-05-28**:
Congratulations!, 1) Hope this page (http://www.openrtp.jp/openhrp3/en/users_manual.html) helps, you can speepd up the simulation by changing parameters in http://www.openrtp.jp/openhrp3/en/um_simulation_view.html. But basically this is slow due to precise dynamics simulation.

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2012-05-28**:
I would appreciate if you can summarise the debugging process as new the answerer post

**Comment by [TurtleBot_Fan](https://answers.ros.org/users/702/turtlebot_fan/) on 2012-05-29**:
For some reason, this forum interface is now limiting me to only about 300 characters and sometimes much less. There is something wrong with this forum interface. Is there anywhere else I can list the debugging summarization?  I was able to insert a seemingly unlimited number of characters before...

**Comment by [TurtleBot_Fan](https://answers.ros.org/users/702/turtlebot_fan/) on 2012-05-29**:
The previous post reached my posting character limit!?

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2012-05-29**:
How about  post as new answer. I suppose you can write longer information

**Comment by [TurtleBot_Fan](https://answers.ros.org/users/702/turtlebot_fan/) on 2012-05-29**:
Please see new post:    Need help with VRML model of HRP-4C